# deserializing compressed file from a vector of bytes

Tags: kdb

Both `read1` and `get` will implicitly decompress a compressed file. If I have a c function that returns the contents of the compressed file as a list of bytes, is there anyway to to deserialize it to same result as if i called `get` on the underlying file?

For uncompressed files, i can change the header and use `-9!` to deserialize. but compressed files are quite different than the output of `-18!`

Comment: Just a note for others: This is already answered in KDB google group : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/personal-kdbplus/ZUM6jG9j_LA